# Verify OAuth Token then provide my own token

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I'm struggling about the best way to go about this.

We have a mobile app where the user can login using various 3rd party providers (Facebook / Google etc).

The app then sends the token to the c# web api for registration of the user (or login if they exist).

The only way I can see to implement OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider is with options i do not have access to (Username & password etc). I want this to verify that the facebook token sent from the application is valid (by using the facebook api - this is not a problem). Then if correct generate a barer token from my api so i know they are authenticated and can map that authentication to a user in the DB.

Everything online seems to only cater for the web api end either accepting a username and password or getting the server to get the facebook (google etc) token to begin with.

I want the API authentication to be based on the user so I can use the standard [Authorize] and Identity system in .net.

Thanks all and I hope that makes sense.